# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToWebRoot' beyond the root web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an application and I ran into this error (that you can see in the title of this post) and I can't find the solution anywhere. This error points to the following lines of code:

```
    <protocols>
        <add name="net.tcp" processHandlerType="System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.TcpProcessProtocolHandler, System.ServiceModel.WasHosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            appDomainHandlerType="System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.TcpAppDomainProtocolHandler, System.ServiceModel.WasHosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            validate="false" />
        <add name="net.pipe" processHandlerType="System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.NamedPipeProcessProtocolHandler, System.ServiceModel.WasHosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            appDomainHandlerType="System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.NamedPipeAppDomainProtocolHandler, System.ServiceModel.WasHosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            validate="false" />
        <add name="net.msmq" processHandlerType="System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.MsmqProcessProtocolHandler, System.ServiceModel.WasHosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            appDomainHandlerType="System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.MsmqAppDomainProtocolHandler, System.ServiceModel.WasHosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            validate="false" />
        <add name="msmq.formatname" processHandlerType="System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.MsmqIntegrationProcessProtocolHandler, System.ServiceModel.WasHosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            appDomainHandlerType="System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.MsmqIntegrationAppDomainProtocolHandler, System.ServiceModel.WasHosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            validate="false" />
    </protocols>
```

I was having no problem debugging the app, but now I always get this error.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: seems like you have placed this protocols element outside of the allowed files (or just copy-pasted the root web.config) : see machineToWebRoot in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228245(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks ! The link you provided was very useful. Thanks one more time for the quick and awesome answer =)